# Append a series of objects in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop, frontend

So I have been working on this feature for a react.js app that I am developing. Firstly, record a group of user inputs, first and last name and address. Secondly, create ONE card object for each group of inputs. Thirdly, store each card object into a new object called List. Right now I am having troubles to append card object into the List object. My codes are the following.

```
const InputField = () => {
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("");
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
    const [address, setAddress] = useState("");
    const [card, setCard] = useState({});
    const [list, setList] = useState({});

    const lastNameUpdate = e => {
        setLastName(e.target.value)
    }

    const firstNameUpdate = e => {
        setFirstName(e.target.value)
    }

    const addressUpdate = e => {
        setAddress(e.target.value)
    }

    const cardUpdate = (e,card) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setCard([
            {last_name:lastName},
            {first_name:firstName},
            {st_address:address}
        ])
        setList(prevState=>({
            s:{...prevState.list,...card}
        }))
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(list)
    },[card,list])

    return (
        <div className="user-input-field">
            <form type='submit'onSubmit={cardUpdate}>
            <label>Last Name:</label>
            <input type='text'value={lastName}onChange={lastNameUpdate}></input>
            <label>First Name:</label>
            <input type='text'value={firstName}onChange={firstNameUpdate}></input>
            <label>Address:</label>
            <textarea type='text'value={address}onChange={addressUpdate}></textarea>
            <input type='submit'></input>
        </form>
    </div>
  )
};
```

Apparently, I tried concat, but I have learned concat doesn't work for appending objects. Pseudo code:

```
a card_x object = {first name_x, last name_x, address_x}
a list object = {card_1, card_2, card_3...}
```

What should I do here?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. Your code and intent seems to imply a list, but you're using an object keyed by `s`. You're then nesting a bunch of objects but destructuring `card` at the root level of that object. Why not just use an array?

Comment: `concat doesn't work for appending objects` - what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes:

1. pass the object instead of list
2. list default value to be [] instead of {}

This should work.

```
const InputField = () => {
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("");
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
  const [address, setAddress] = useState("");
  const [card, setCard] = useState({});
  const [list, setList] = useState([]); // update to []

  const lastNameUpdate = e => {
    setLastName(e.target.value);
  };

  const firstNameUpdate = e => {
    setFirstName(e.target.value);
  };

  const addressUpdate = e => {
    setAddress(e.target.value);
  };

  const cardUpdate = (e, card) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setCard({ lastName, firstName, address });
    setList([...list, { lastName, firstName, address }]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(list);
  }, [card, list]);

  return (
    <div className="user-input-field">
      <form type="submit" onSubmit={cardUpdate}>
        <label>Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" value={lastName} onChange={lastNameUpdate}></input>
        <label>First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" value={firstName} onChange={firstNameUpdate}></input>
        <label>Address:</label>
        <textarea
          type="text"
          value={address}
          onChange={addressUpdate}
        ></textarea>
        <input type="submit"></input>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you, it runs with NO error, but each object in the List array is empty

Comment: @LearnerSamuelX, my bad, and no change at onChange callbacks. I just updated the answer.  Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try having a variable containing the new updated list of cards and `setList` to that new cards list :

```
const cardUpdate = (e, card) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setCard([{ last_name: lastName }, { first_name: firstName }, { st_address: address }]);

  // new cards list
  const cardList = [...list, card];

  // update the state
  setList(cardList);
};
```